# When try to go next page using selinum it gives list index out of range error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to go to every next page using the below code.
it collects data from page Number 1. but when I try to loop it and go to the next page it gives me an error.

Web page : https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies

this is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

url = 'https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies'
service = Service('linkto crome driver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(12)

for j in range(346):
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')
    for i in range(len(divs)):
        time.sleep(10)
        d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')

        RN = ''

        d[i].click()
        time.sleep(12)

        try:
            RNData = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile-header"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div')
            RN = RNData[0].text.split(':')[1].strip()
            print(RN)
        except Exception as e5:
            pass

        if i == (len(divs) - 1):
            pass
        else:
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    bt = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="-pagination-next-btn"]')
    bt[0].click()
```

This is the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What code line gives that error?

Comment: bt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="-pagination-next-btn"]') and
bt[0].click()

Comment: If you want to get multiple elements, then use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`

Comment: Thanks my mistake, I will correct it on the code, I change it to find_elements_by_xpath but still doesn't work

Comment: Also why are you trying to use index in the btn- the btn has same xpath locator in all the pages. There is not need to use index in that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is as following:

```
bt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="-pagination-next-btn"]')
```

returns a single web element object, it's not a list, so you can't apply indexing on it with `bt[0]`
UPD:
After changing from `find_element_by_xpath` to `find_elements_by_xpath` you still getting `IndexError: list index out of range` there because you were in the inner page and performed driver back action.
Immediately after that you are trying to get the next page button while the main page is still not loaded. This actually returns you an empty list

```
bt = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="-pagination-next-btn"]')
```

that's why you can't apply `bt[0]` on an empty list object.

Comment: Thanks my mistake, I will correct it on the code, I change it to find_elements_by_xpath but still doesn't work

Comment: what is the error now? On what line? No element found?

Comment: same Error, IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you see if the bt list is empty? In a run mode, not in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks, After adding some time to render js & doing some modifications I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
if i == (len(divs) - 1):
    pass
else:
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

After clicking the last link, you are not navigating back to the initial page, which is where the pagination button is. I don't think you need this condition at all, so your code could be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

url = 'https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies'
service = Service('linkto crome driver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(12)

for j in range(346):
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')
    for i in range(len(divs)):
        time.sleep(10)
        d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')

        RN = ''

        d[i].click()
        time.sleep(12)

        try:
            RNData = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile-header"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div')
            RN = RNData[0].text.split(':')[1].strip()
            print(RN)
        except Exception as e5:
            pass

        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    bt = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="-pagination-next-btn"]')
    bt[0].click()
```

Comment: Thanks again, After adding some time to render js & doing some modifications I was able to fix the issue.